# find dates and times in a document

Tags: parsing, time, web-crawler, information-retrieval

time, date and time+date can be represented in multiple ways
Ex.

- today 18:00
- next monday 4pm
- 12 Jan
- 1/1/13
- today evening at 5
- many many more

I need to find a way to find and retrieve time and dates in these formats and collect them . 
a way is to have a list of keywords , find them and look at the words before and after that.

beside that , the more matches are better , so  I need more patterns to compare to find if a sequence is a date or not. that could be time consuming .

is it the best way to do ?

Comment: Hi. I noticed you just deleted a question that attracted a couple of downvotes. I don't think that's the right response - if you are getting downvotes, it is a signal that the post is in need of improvement. In this case, you'd not posted enough code to replicate the problem, and rectifying that might have garnered some upvotes to neutralise the downvotes.

Comment: shouldn't downvoters just post a comment that , hey " bad poster ! Post better ! ?" or just leave a Downvote and make me think that I  asked wrong question at wrong time and place?

Comment: http://www.datejs.com/ can help you with the parsing part of your question. But finding just any date/time related string in an arbitrary text is another thing.

Comment: I need to do it in PHP and at backend , and no Node.js

Comment: it seems I need multiple regexes